# Which is the right way to handle events in JAVA?

Tags: java, event-handling

Wich is the right way, the programmers use to handle events in JAVA? The question is, is it OK, to auto generate code double-clicking button in design view of Eclipse like this

```
btn_add_game.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

MY CODE TO EXECUTE;
            }
        });
```

or it's necessery to write the class that implements action listener and then write the code?

Also, on the same subject, is it normal to use Designer view in eclipse or hard-core programmers use code only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have written is perfectly fine. It is an **anonymous inner class** and I don't think that having those around is a code smell.

Imagine if you have implemented all listeners as separate classes. You would have ended up with a proliferation of classes which are essentially anonymous functions (like labdas in other languages).

So **yes, go ahead** and use generated listeners.

You other question is a religious one. Half of the programmers will say don't use it the other half will tell you to use it. It all comes down as preference. If the Designer in question generates quality code then use it otherwise do not.

Comment: +1 To some extent, I believe his first question is also a religious one, especially with the IDE's available today. I would personally recommend using separate class for listeners in most cases, but this is only a personal opinion. I've had such debate at my job a few times.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on your company's policies, and how much you want your code to be separated into logical units. The code you have provided in your question is OK; it will allow you to handle the event.

However, I usually prefer having a separate class, which extends the listener interface I need, rather than having a bunch of annonymous inner classes. It generates cleaner code (in my opinion), and makes it easier to maintain, or add new functionalities later on. But keep in mind that this is only my opinion (Adam posted a perfectly valid answer which goes against my opinion).

As far as coding a GUI is concerned, I never use a GUI builder, I find I lack control over the GUI components, layout and behavior. I always code it by hand, using the appropriate `LayoutManager`, or combination of managers. But, if your user interface is simple enough, and you don't want to be spending time learning how to handle GUI in Java, then using a builder is a perfectly valid option.

Comment: @AdamArold Good catch. Hail to my french canadian heritage :P Thanks for noticing ;)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your need.

1. If there is one action than use directly,  as you show at your question.
2. If there is multiple action than you should implements `ActionListener` for maintenance and reduce boilerplate code.